# How to fix HTML email numbered list causing tabs after list exceeds 99?

Tags: python, html, email, smtp, html-email

I have a Python script that uses `smtplib`, `email.mime.multipart`, and `email.mime.text` to send an email with a numbered list.  After the list exceeds 99 it inserts tabs after the number and messes up the formatting.

The only thing that has worked so far has been inserting a line break after each number to keep formatting consistent, but it doesn't look as good.

```py
for i in range(0:200):
    body_row = '<li>First line here <br>Second line here</li>'
    body_total += body_row
body_total = "Total List" + "<ol>" + body_total + "</ol>" + "<br>"
```

The output looks like this:

```
99. First line here
    Second line here
100.    First line here
    Second line here
101.    First line here
    Second line here
```

Does anyone know of an easy way to fix this other than my line break solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question has little do with Python programming, as it is primarily about how to format something in HTML.

I think the answer is to use the HTML `<ol>` [ordered list](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_lists.htm) tag, which will do what you want (and you don't have to explicitly number the elements yourself).

```html
<ol>
    <li>
        First line here<br />
        Second line here
    </li>
    <li>
        First line here<br />
        Second line here
    </li>
    <li>
        First line here<br />
        Second line here
    </li>
    <li>
        First line here<br />
        Second line here
    </li>
       .
       .
       .
</ol>
```

Result rendered by a web browser:

[image: screenshot of result rendered by a web browser]

Comment: I forgot to specify that I am wrapping the above statement in <ol> and I'm not rendering in a browser, it is being rendered incorrectly in an email

Comment: @John: Try rendering it in another email client or if possible a web browser because it's possible that rendering is being done poorly by whatever software you have been using — and there's probably little you can about that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @martineau.  It does look like the problem only occurs in Outlook and looks fine in Gmail.  Shouldn't really be an issue because the list rarely goes past 99.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Saw this late and just adding to the answer given. It might have been easier to do it with tables. Ordered list doesn't have good support as you have found out. You could have done two column rows with incrementing numbers from your loop on the left and data on the right.

Comment: @Syfer: True, HTML tables can be (and often are) used to do better page-layout because they give you more control over the appearance of the document displayed — although I not sure it would be been easier (feel free to post your own answer). It also seems ironic to have to do this in mid-2019 because Outlook has poor support for tag that's been part of the HTML specification since at least 1999.

Comment: I get what you mean about Outlook but if you are in email marketing (or any email related field) you end up supporting email clients even if we hate them. Just posted an answer hope its a second alternative. Had to do a crash course in Python just to get the loop right.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way. My first attempt at python so go easy on me with this one.

```
print """<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
    <tbody>"""
for x in range(0, 200):
    rowData = """        <tr>
        <td> %d</td> 
        <td>first line<br> second line</td> 
    </tr>""" % (x)
    print rowData

print """    </tbody> 
</table>"""
```

I used print to see how my table structure is, you can change these to variables. The structure above will ensure your numbers are right on all email clients and the columns will be the same across all as well. Below is a screenshot of how the output will look.

[image]

Comment: I think one might want `<td align="right">%d</td>` for the number column (although Outlook may not support it). Your Python coding is basically OK, but `print` is a function in the current version 3.x (it used to be a statement).

Comment: @martineau if a value is parsed thru then its just text for Outlook and it will read the opening and closing `td` as HTML and render just fine. I know this will work as I have done more complex ones using XSLT in emails.

Comment: I know it's just text, was only indicating that is should be right-aligned in the cell since it's digits representing a numeric value.

Comment: The alignment can be anything from right left or center. It all depends. To simulate bullet points I use center as it looks better but yeah it's all on a users opinion.